# Disable tooltip only for months and days in Highcharts

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

Hi highcharts community !

In my angular 4 project, I am trying to disable just the days and the months in the tooltip of my horizontal bar chart, to just make appear the hour minutes and secondes, if anyone know how to make it?

I tried with the property `dateTimeLabelFormats` without success

Thanks in advance

horizontalbar.ts:

```
constructor(public userService3: UserService3) {

  const timeZoneOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

  const Highcharts = require('highcharts');

    Highcharts.setOptions({
  global: {
   timezoneOffset: timeZoneOffset
  },
      });


       this.options = {
        title : { text : '' },
        chart: {  type: 'area',
                    label: {
                      format: '{data: %B}'
                    }},
        legend: { enabled: false },
        credits: { enabled: false },
        xAxis: { type: 'datetime',
                //  day: '%H',
                startOnTick: false,
                endOnTick: false,
                minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                tickInterval: 36e5 * 2, // two hours
                },
        yAxis: { min: 0,
          max: 100,
           labels: {
              enabled: true
          },
             title: {
             text: null
           },
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
              color: '#648e59',
              fillOpacity: 0.8,
              fillColor: '#648e59',
              pointInterval: 36e5 * 2 // two hours
                  }
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'Taux de fonctionnement',
          data: [],
        }]
       };
   }
  saveInstance(chartInstance) {
    this.chart = chartInstance;
    console.log(chartInstance);
}

  public ngOnInit () {
  this.dataSubscription = this.userService3.getData().subscribe((data) 
 => {
  this.options.series[0].data = data.data.operating_details;
  console.log(data);
   });
}
   ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.dataSubscription){
 this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
 }
   }
     public hideDem2(): void {
   this.hideMeup = !this.hideMeup;
    this.hideMeup = !this.hideMeup;

    this.hideItup = !this.hideItup;
        if (this.hideItup) {
          this.opened.emit(true);
        } else {
          this.closed.emit(false);
        }
           console.log(this.hideItup);
      }

   }
```

horizontalbar.html:

```
      <chart [options]="options" (load)="saveInstance($event.context)">
      <!--    <point (select)="onPointSelect($event)"></point> -->
      </chart>
```

Comment: hey Emile, do you happen to have a pic of what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "tick in my horizontal bar chart," you mean the axis labels, you could add the following to your `xAxis` options:

```
labels: {
    formatter: function () {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.value);
    },
},
```

That should return only the hours, minutes, and seconds of your axis labels in the format `H:M:S`.

More information about `Highcharts.dateFormat()` can be found here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Highcharts.numberFormat.

The `Highcharts.dateFormat()` function uses PHP's `strftime` formatting rules (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).

I hope this information is helpful to you.

---

**Update**: Per Emile's comments, the tick in question was the chart's **tooltip**. In this case, what you would need to modify is as follows:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.x);
    },
},
```

See the following resources from the Highcharts documentation:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter
- http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/formatter-simple/

Comment: yes it is on the xAxis options, but my issue isn't on the label it is on the `tick` , the small grey window who appears when your mouse is hovering the chart

Comment: Oh! That should be the tooltip. The same method applies, except that you would use `this.x` instead of `this.value`. See http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter and the demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/formatter-simple/

Comment: Ahright then I'll edit my post thank you so much and I'll let you know if it works

Comment: it works adding this ` tooltip: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.x);
                        }
                    },` could you please edit your post then it could maybe help someone else ?

Comment: @EmileCantero I'm glad this worked out for you. I've updated my answer per your request. Have an awesome day!

Comment: thanks have a awesome one too and see you again around ;)